# How to pack complicated custom class into Jasper DataSource object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Consider I have this customized class that want to put value of every member variable on a single Jasper report

```
public class Manifest {
private IMasterOrder masterOrder;

private Employee supervisor;

private Employee assistant;

private Date arrivalTime;

private Date departureTime;

private IOrder copOrderFit;
}
```

Here the member `copOrderFit` is with type of another class `Order` which contains a List of String I want to put on the same Jasper report as well.

So in the Java code, which `JRDataSource` implementation class I suppose to use to pack the manifest class or is there better solution for this question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `JRDataSource` implementations represent tabular data. Individual fields (such as `arrivalTime`) are usually passed to the report as parameters.

Comment: @lhballoti thank you for the quick response. Could you please speak more about how to solve that IOrder class in Jasper data source?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are asking, you have a collection of Manifests you want to use as your datasource?

Comment: @jschoen. Thank you. Actually I plan to pass a single manifest instance to Jasper template and within the manifest class there are several collection member variable, each one hold data of a small table. So actually I plan to put four small tables on one Jasper report along with other single variables like arrival time, departure time...etc. I am not sure whether this is the best design but please share any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: That is most likely not the best way to accomplish this goal. I would make each small table a sub-report. You could then pass in a separate data source for each sub-report as a parameter for the top level report. You may be able to pull it off doing it the way you want, but I can't think of an easy way off the top of my head. Unless each small table has a set number of rows in each run then I think you will have major issues trying to get everything to layout correctly.